# Copying file names into an array with C

Tags: c

I'm attempting to find all the files in a directory of a certain type (hardcoded here to tif) and copy them into an array. Everything compiles cleanly (gcc -Wall gives no errors or warnings) but there are some memory issues. Though the program I've written seems to run cleanly (no segfaults), some of the file names are weird characters you get when you've got something other than ascii values in your string. This led me to run with valgrind, which shows errors (output below) but I can't track down what the actual problem is. In some directories, valgrind it self segfaults (the program runs clean in the same dir).

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <search.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



#define min(X, Y)  ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))

int exitStatus = 0;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* array_find
*
* ARGS - Takes a pointer to a string, a pointer to an array of strings, and an
* int representing the length of the array.
*
* RETURN - returns an int indicating the first index of the key in the array,
* or -1 if the key was not found
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int array_find(char *key, char *argv[], int argc){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG_array_find
        printf("strncmp(%s, %s, %d) = %d\n", key, argv[i], min(strlen(key), strlen(argv[i])), strncmp(key, argv[i], min(strlen(key), strlen(argv[i]))));
        #endif
        if (strncmp(key, argv[i], min(strlen(key), strlen(argv[i]))) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* ends_with
*
* ARGS - str = string to be checked
*        sub = string to look for
*
* RETURN - Returns true if str ends with sub or both strings are NULL.
           False otherwise.
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

bool ends_with(char *str, char *sub){
    if (str == NULL && sub == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (str == NULL || sub == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char *last_instance_of_sub = rindex(str, *sub); //Finds the last index of the first char of sub
    int sub_len = strlen(sub);
    if (last_instance_of_sub == NULL || strlen(last_instance_of_sub) != sub_len)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return strncmp(last_instance_of_sub, sub, sub_len) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*Parse args*/
    DIR *dir;
    int index = array_find("-d", argv, argc);
    char *dirname;
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        dirname = argv[index + 1];
        dir = opendir(dirname);
    }
    else
    {
        dirname = getcwd(NULL, 0);
        if (dirname == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error getting current directory name.");
            exit(1);
        }
        dir = opendir(dirname);
    }
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        perror(dirname);
        exit(1);
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG_MAIN
        printf("dirname = %s\n", dirname);
    #endif

    int threads = 1;
    index = array_find("-t", argv, argc);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        threads = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    #ifdef DEBUG_MAIN
        printf("threads = %d\n", threads);
    #endif

    struct dirent *entry = readdir(dir);
    int num_files = 0;
    while (entry != NULL)
    {
        if (ends_with(entry->d_name, ".tif")){
            #ifdef DEBUG_MAIN
                printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
            #endif
            num_files++;
        }
        entry = readdir(dir);
    }

    if (closedir(dir) != 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to close directory.");
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG_MAIN
        printf("Num files = %d\n", num_files);
    #endif

    dir = opendir(dirname);
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        perror(dirname);
        exit(1);
    }

    entry = readdir(dir);

    char *file_names[num_files];
    int i = 0;
    for(; entry != NULL; i++)
    {
        if (ends_with(entry->d_name, ".tif")){
            file_names[i] = strdup(entry->d_name);
            if (file_names[i] == NULL)
            {
                perror("Could not create the filename array.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        entry = readdir(dir);
    }

/*    #ifdef DEBUG_MAIN*/
        for (i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", file_names[i]);
/*            free(file_names[i]);*/
        }
/*    #endif*/



    free(dir);
    return exitStatus;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
    ==24488== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24488== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24488== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24488== Command: ./myprogram -d /home/chris/Pictures/Catalinas\ with\ Christie/Processed/
==24488== 
dirname = /home/chris/Pictures/Catalinas with Christie/Processed/
threads = 1
cacti2_lzn.tif
DSC_2139_lzn.tif
DSC_1512_lzn.tif
DSC_1296_lzn.tif
DSC_1577_lzn.tif
DSC_1658_lzn.tif
DSC_1293_lzn.tif
DSC_1631_lzn.tif
DSC_1418_lzn.tif
DSC_1315_2crop_lzn.tif
DSC_1377_lzn2crop.tif
DSC_2167_lzn.tif
1981-1985-HDR3_lzn2.tif
DSC_2129_lzn.tif
DSC_1448_lzn.tif
DSC_1607_lzn.tif
DSC_1564_lzn.tif
DSC_2052-DSC_2072_lzn.tif
DSC_1487_lzn.tif
DSC_1591_2_lzn.tif
DSC_2124_lzn.tif
DSC_1622_lzn.tif
DSC_2157_lzn.tif
DSC_1685_lzn.tif
Num files = 24
cacti2_lzn.tif
DSC_2139_lzn.tif
DSC_1512_lzn.tif
DSC_1296_lzn.tif
DSC_1577_lzn.tif
DSC_1658_lzn.tif
==24488== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24488==    at 0x4C2D7C2: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24488==    by 0x4EA4ECB: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==24488==    by 0x400D52: main (batch-convert.c:161)
==24488== 
==24488== Invalid read of size 1
==24488==    at 0x4C2D7C2: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24488==    by 0x4EA4ECB: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==24488==    by 0x400D52: main (batch-convert.c:161)
==24488==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==24488== 
==24488== 
==24488== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==24488==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==24488==    at 0x4C2D7C2: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24488==    by 0x4EA4ECB: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==24488==    by 0x400D52: main (batch-convert.c:161)
==24488==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==24488==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==24488==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==24488==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==24488==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==24488== 
==24488== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24488==     in use at exit: 33,243 bytes in 25 blocks
==24488==   total heap usage: 26 allocs, 1 frees, 66,051 bytes allocated
==24488== 
==24488== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24488==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24488==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24488==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24488==    still reachable: 33,243 bytes in 25 blocks
==24488==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24488== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==24488== 
==24488== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24488== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==24488== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It's been a while since I've used C at all, but as I understand it (from the man pages), strdup should use malloc to allocate memory on the heap for the copy of the string. Before I remembered the strdup function, I had tried to do exactly that manually, and had the same errors. I thought maybe my code was flawed, and thought the strdup function would take care of it, but apparently there is some other issue.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT 1:
As per requests, I've added the full source of the program. Also, for those saying to check i against num_files, as you'll see, I count the number of tif files ahead of time, so I know the exact number of files that will be copied into the array, thus checking the index isn't necessary.

Also, as a note, the program was compiled with DEBUG_MAIN defined, so anything in an #ifdef DEBUG_MAIN block does run. No other debug flags were defined.

Comment: What is the initial value of `entry`?

Comment: 1. It would help if you posted an actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), rather than just a snippet. 2. Does your program work in a directory with ASCII-only filenames? 3. The Valgrind output does not help at all without the corresponding source code (and the line numbers to go with it)

Comment: Also, do you remember to update `num_files` with the final value of `i`? Are you returning the `file_names` array (with automatic storage class) to the caller? Posting a complete example would resolve all these questions without needing to ask.

Comment: @user4815162342: Agreed, there are about a million different things that could be wrong, from structures going out of scope to multi-byte charset issues, to error conditions not being handled correctly.

Comment: But +1 for at least attempting to debug it with valgrind, so much more than most of the questions we get here. :)

Comment: The valgrind output does not belong to this code, I can't see the call to puts

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul By the time `puts` is called, it's probably too late - the `file_names` array (or its part) is filled with garbage.

Comment: can you show us everything related to `entry` ? and what is the value of `num_files` ?

Comment: It works fine for me, so I second the SSCCE request. BTW: don't use min as a macro, you're evaluating it's "arguments" twice (strlen). Also in array_find there's no need to use strncmp and ends_with seems needlesly complicated. Just my $0.02

Comment: You can use `strcmp()` instead of `strncmp()` in `ends_with()` since you know the strings are both valid and the same length. I don't think that's a factor in your problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you have any entries that don't match your pattern (such as the `.` and `..` entries), you skip the corresponding entry in the array.  It also means you go writing outside your `file_names` array. You should only increment `i` when the file name matches.

Using `getcwd()` instead of just using `.` for the current directory works, but is hardly necessary.

Using `free(dir)` instead of `closedir(dir)` is an unmitigated disaster.

The command line argument handling is unusual.  As originally written, it would accept `-delete` as equivalent to `-d`.  That's not good style.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool ends_with(char *str, char *sub);
int array_find(char *key, char *argv[], int argc);

int array_find(char *key, char *argv[], int argc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(key, argv[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

bool ends_with(char *str, char *sub)
{
    if (str == NULL && sub == NULL)
        return true;
    if (str == NULL || sub == NULL)
        return false;
    char *last_instance_of_sub = rindex(str, *sub);
    size_t sub_len = strlen(sub);
    if (last_instance_of_sub == NULL || strlen(last_instance_of_sub) != sub_len)
        return false;
    return strcmp(last_instance_of_sub, sub) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int index = array_find("-d", argv, argc);
    char *dirname;
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        dirname = argv[index + 1];
    }
    else
    {
        dirname = getcwd(NULL, 0);
        if (dirname == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error getting current directory name.");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    DIR *dir = opendir(dirname);
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        perror(dirname);
        exit(1);
    }
    char suffix[] = ".c";

    printf("dirname = %s\n", dirname);

    struct dirent *entry;
    int num_files = 0;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (ends_with(entry->d_name, suffix))
            num_files++;
    }

    if (closedir(dir) != 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to close directory.");
    }

    printf("Num files = %d\n", num_files);

    dir = opendir(dirname);
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        perror(dirname);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *file_names[num_files];
    int i = 0;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (ends_with(entry->d_name, suffix))
        {
            file_names[i] = strdup(entry->d_name);
            if (file_names[i++] == NULL)
            {
                perror("Could not create the filename array.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    assert(i <= num_files);
    if (i < num_files)
        num_files = i;

    for (i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", file_names[i]);
        free(file_names[i]);
    }

    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sort of pissed off at myself that I didn't see that I was advancing through the array regardless of whether I added a file or not. My debugging skills have gone to crap in the past few months. Anyway, thanks for the help, and thanks for the other tips as well, I'll take them into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

in your code this part `for(; entry != NULL; i++)` is way too dangerous , for example lets say that the value of `num_files` is 1000 , what if a given directory contains 1002 entries , then you'll have a problem.
replace it with `for(; entry != NULL && i < num_files ; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

The index of the array should be checked:

```
i<num_files
```